# CORS not working with Angular 2 in chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, soap, cors

I am using javascript code to call soap webservice deployed on weblogic and developed in java using jaxws. From IE11 I am getting response from SOAP but from chrome I am getting below error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
 Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. 
 The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

I have added cors extension in chrome and then I got below new error:

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

I also set request headers as below:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Custom-Header');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE');
```

but still no success.

Below is my code snippet to call my webservices deployed on weblogic

```
    var soapMessage = this.createSOAPMessage();

    function createCORSRequest(method, url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        } else {
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    }

    var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST','http://IPAddress:7001/Path/ServiceImplService?WSDL');
    if(!xhr){
    console.log('XHR Issue');
    return;
    }

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Custom-Header');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE');

    xhr.send(soapMessage);

    var result
    xhr.onload = function(){
        result = xhr.responseText;
        console.log('===Result====> '+result);
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: `I also set request headers as below:` - you don't send those headers, those **must** be received for CORS ... CORS is controlled by the server, the client can't tell the server **give me your resource regardless of your settings** :p

Comment: So do you mean I have to handle cors request at server side, not from our javascript?

Comment: That's where CORS is controlled from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this class in your service :

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestCtx, ContainerResponseContext responseCtx) throws IOException {

        responseCtx.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to point out that `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` will also need `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` unless the OP removes those (pointless) headers from the request

Comment: By using this class I am able to resolve the problem but is this a real solution? Because when I won't have access to services then how can I manage this issue?
I am new to this approach so just trying to understand.
And thanks for the help

Comment: This is a real solution.